# Block with select() untill client acquisition or loss

Tags: c, sockets, unix, file-descriptor, unix-socket

I need to know whether a client connected/disconnected and handle it.

This was my only idea:

```
while(!serverStop)
{
    fd_set rfds, wfdsBefore, wfdsAfter;

    FD_ZERO(&rfds);
    FD_SET(serverFd, &rfds);

    FD_ZERO(&wfdsBefore);
    fillWithClientFds(&wfdsBefore); // clients only listen for messages
    wfdsAfter = wfdsBefore;

    while(1)
    {
        select(notimportant, &rfds, &wfdsAfter, NULL, NULL);

        if (FD_ISSET(serverFd, &rfds)) // new client appeared
            break;

        if (doSetsDiffer(&wfdsBefore, &wfdsAfter)) // some client disconnected (doesn't work)
            break;
    }

    // inform connected clients about disconnected ones

}
```

Not only busy waiting would occur but also this approach doesn't even work (`wfdsAfter` doesn't change despite the fact that client closed the socket).

Is there any way to do it? The only requirement is to not use multithreading.

`serverFd` was made with `PF_UNIX` and `SOCK_STREAM` flags.

Comment: This is not busy-waiting. `select()` blocks! To know that a working socket disconnected, you must `read()` it and get 0 bytes in return, or attempt to `write()` to a broken socket and fail. Treat sockets as connected unless one of these two things happen

Comment: In this situation it doesn't, because `select()` immediately returns descriptors to write to even if their corresponding sockets are already closed.

Comment: Clients don't send anything so `read()` will always return 0 and I don't want to send any meaningless data via `write()` just to check if the connection is still up (unless I can send 0 bytes and still fail).

Comment: Your understanding is incorrect. A difference in the read and write sets doesn't mean a client disappeared. The only way to reliably detect a broken TCP connection is to write to it. If there is no data being exchanged what exactly are you wasting sockets and connections for?

Comment: There is data exchange. Server informs all connected clients about new connection/disconnection.

Comment: The "socket" metaphor is getting to you. Sockets are not really "connected", nothing is constantly happening -- a socket is said to be"connected" if reads and writes are expected to succeed, nothing more. "Disconnecting" is only ceasing to assume that. Unless a blocking read returns nothing, or a write fails, you can continue to assume connection. Perhaps you could use `zeroMQ` sockets instead of naked ones, those can track connectivity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should place each client file descriptor in the read descriptors (rfds) set after it connects, and, when the file descriptor is subsequently returned as readable, attempt to read from the socket.

First, if your client is really sending nothing (and *isn't* yet disconnected), its socket will never be marked as readable. That seems like it would solve your issue since you say the client never actually sends anything: it won't be marked readable then until the client disconnects.

But even if the client sends data, the file descriptor would only be marked readable if there *were* data available *OR* the client had disconnected. You can easily then distinguish by attempting to read the socket. The return value would be either number of bytes read (if there are data), or zero if the client has disconnected.

(Servers often add the O_NONBLOCK option to sockets to ensure they get notified when the client has data to send but want to ensure they don't block waiting for data from a client. With that option, read still returns 0 when the client has disconnected. With the option, if the client is still around, but there is no data available, the read call would return -1 with errno set to EAGAIN/EWOULDBLOCK.)

One other nuance I haven't explained is that it is possible to close data delivery in one direction while allowing it to continue in the other (see shutdown(2) if you care about this).

Answer (score 1):

You are putting the client sockets in the *write* descriptor set.  You need to put them in the *read* descriptor set instead.

When a server socket has at least 1 pending client request, it is *readable*. You can call `accept()` to accept a client.

When a socket has data in its inbound buffer, or *its connected peer has disconnected*, it is *readable*, not *writable*. You can call `read()` to differentiate. `read()` returns > 0 on inbound data, 0 on graceful disconnect, and -1 on error.

A socket is *writable* when it has available space in its outbound buffer. If  `write()` fails with an `EWOULDBLOCK` error, the outbound buffer has filled up, and the socket is no longer *writable*.  When the buffer clears up some space, the socket will become *writable* again.

Also, `select()` modifies the `fdset`s you pass to it, so you need to reset `rfds` on every loop iteration. To avoid that, you can use `(e)poll()` instead.

So, you need something more like this instead:

```
fd_set rfds;

while (!serverStop)
{
    FD_ZERO(&rfds);
    FD_SET(serverFd, &rfds);
    fillWithClientFds(&rfds); // clients only listen for messages

    if (select(notimportant, &rfds, NULL, NULL, NULL) < 0)
        break;

    if (FD_ISSET(serverFd, &rfds)) // new client appeared
    {
        // call accept(), add client to connected list...
    }

    // clear disconnected list...

    for (each client in connected list)
    {
        if (FD_ISSET(clientFd, &rfds))
        {
            int nBytes = read(clientFd, ...);
            if (nBytes > 0)
            {
                // handle client data as needed ...
            }
            else if (nBytes == 0)
            {
                // add client to disconnected list
            }
            else
            {
                // handle error...
                // possibly add client to disconnected list...
            }
        }
    }

    for (each client in disconnected list)
    {
        // remove client from connected list...
    }

    for (each client in disconnected list)
    {
        // inform connected clients
    }
}
```

Comment: A socket *is* writable when there is space in its send buffer, and select() tells you exactly that. It doesn't know the history.